# Running Keycloak in Kubernetes with readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, keycloak

I am playing around with Keycloak docker image and my goal is to create Helm chart with hardening that includes also `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true` in the `securityContext` of running pod.

I am following the guide [Running Keycloak in a container](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers).

I would like to keep the possibility for users of my Helm chart to set the options and configure Keycloak through the environment variables, see [All configuration](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config).

As I understood from the guide, I cannot run the standard Keycloak container with the `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true` because it always build the keycloak based on provided options and I need to build my own optimized Keycloak docker image, for example using similar Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
ENV KC_CACHE_STACK=kubernetes
ENV JAVA_OPTS_APPEND=-Djgroups.dns.query=keycloak-service-internal-headless
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
# ENV KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/kc
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance
ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_DB_URL=<DBURL>
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=<DBUSERNAME>
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=<DBPASSWORD>

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

However, it seems that building optimized docker image already pre-bundles options into generated files (`generated-bytecode.jar` etc.) and running optimized image with `start --optimized` ignores the configuration provided through `env` of the Kubernetes manifest generated by Helm chart.

For example, the `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH` variable is ignored when set, when I provide `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH/kc` during building optimized image, it will be stored in the generated files and I cannot change it after.

Is there any description or guidance which options can be configured dynamically and which not when I create optimized Keycloak docker image?

Is there any other proper way how to run the Keycloak docker image with read-only filesystem with option to dynamically set values for options in declarative way?